Ctrl shift v not mirror properly

Some of the postures are almost symmetrically pasted.

And this is the 16th key frame on the left leg.

And this is keyframe 16 (starting at 50) on the right leg.
As you can see, some keyframes of the mirrored and copied right leg move to a different location than the original left leg. I haven't touched anything separately with the rig generated by rigify. I don't know what's wrong. I want to make this movement symmetrical. I need help.

Hello, maybe an opposite bones is not correctly rotated so the mirror doesn't work well? Hard to tell without the file, maybe share just the armature?

I kept comparing left and right, and I couldn't copy and paste the movements of my ankles and toes. I don't understand that if you simply paste, all the movements will be pasted, but it doesn't apply only when you mirror it. I've already asked questions elsewhere because of other parts of the problem, and they've all asked for files, but there's no answer, so I'm worried about file sharing simply because of the models and the people who are taking them out.

As I said you can share the armature only

Never mind, I didn't create some main keyframes for some of them like a fool. I made it by selecting all of them and pressing i, but I don't know why they're missing it. Anyway, this method fixed the problem.
